# How to make buttons click(work) multiple times?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm creating a c# windows form application, and I created a navigation bar with buttons. There are 5 main buttons that appear all the time on the form but I also made sub buttons that appear when you click on the main buttons. When I click once they appear and if I click again on the same button they disappear and it works only once. If I click on the button for the third time or multiple times afterward they don't appear anymore. Can someone please tell me how to make it work properly? This is the code I used in the event handlers:

```
public void Izlez_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!buttonPressed4)
            {
                buttonPressed4 = true;
                logout.Show();
                exit.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                logout.Hide();
                exit.Hide();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The _buttonPressed4_ once true never return false. So you never enter again the show logic. You need to set _buttonPressed4_ to false inside the else block

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm new at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve said, you also need to change `buttonPressed4` to `false` in `else statement`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button2.Visible = false;
}

bool buttonPressed4 = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!buttonPressed4)
    {
        buttonPressed4 = true;
        logout.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        // change buttonPressed4 to false
        buttonPressed4 = false;
        logout.Hide();
    }
}
```